# Why do I get a "#08S01Bad handshake error" while connecting to remote db using Net::MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, perl

I am able to connect to the remote DB using "mysql -h  -u'root' option. The remote db has no password for root. But when I use Net::MySQL it throws a `_#08S01Bad handshake error_`.

```
my $mysql = Net::MySQL->new(
        hostname   => '<ip>',
        database   => '<db>',
        user       => 'root',
        password   => ''
    );
```

The SQL version of the local machine is 5.5.44. I was able to connect to the same remote DB(mysql ver 5.0.45) using the same code from a different machine(mysql ver 5.0.24).

Comment: What version of MySQL Server are you using?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case for you where you need Net::MySQL over DBI with DBD::mysql?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710427/ruby-on-rails-mysql-08s01bad-handshake-downgrade-mysql might be connected. Looks like a similar error.

Comment: @simbabque, I have other modules that are written using Net::MySQL. It worked when I used DBI.

Comment: I have again faced this issue. I upgraded the MySQL version in both the client and server to 5.6.30 and I still face the same error. I am able to access remote server using "mysql -h" or using Perl DBI module. Is there a way to have a wrapper that can interact between Net::MySQL and DBI modules?